# Vue and pdfkit generates an error: not constructor

Tags: vue.js, pdfkit, maker-js

I installed [pdfkit](https://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html#installation) in my Vue.js app then I created a vue component to start creating PDF but on my first test I got an error:

Component script:

```
const pdfkit =  require('pdfkit');
var doc = new pdfkit;
```

But this generates an error:

> pdfkit is not a constructor

How to fix it? Thanks for any suggetsion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to import it in your component with

```
import pdfkit from 'pdfkit'
```

and then create your document with

```
let doc = new pdfkit();
```

Comment: Thanks It looks for another error now: 'data/Helvetica.afm' not found in virtual file system. This exists in node_modules/pdftkit/js/data

Comment: Maybe something wrong in my webpack config. https://github.com/blikblum/pdfkit-webpack-example/blob/master/webpack.config.js After updated the webpack config I got an error in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' which means the build.js is not properly created...

Comment: Fixed! I registered the file as in https://github.com/blikblum/pdfkit-webpack-example/blob/master/src/register-files.js and now it is working well. Thanks